# PHP - How to encode data with RSA256 method?

Tags: php, encryption, jwt, rsa, private-key

I have to do a native JWT Key Method, and i have to use RSA256 method, but when i try this :

```
$getPrivate = openssl_pkey_get_private(".../rsa_private.pem", $passphrase);
openssl_sign($data, $partialSignature, $getPrivate, sha256WithRSAEncryption);
$signature .= $partialSignature;
$function_rsa = base64_encode($signature);
```

or that

```
$encrypt_rsa = openssl_private_encrypt($data, $partialEncrypted, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
$encrypted .= $partialEncrypted;
$function_rsa = base64_encode($encrypted);
```

it won't work correctly, it return me that for the case 1 :

```
F/BXtAkMLK7W/2wGw2Gi/s1XT+2UphCafVug/oa/OQ62IXwblaS7vVyx5jyB1HTNMz/hlTGmr0ukj3J9lyDAunbP/2nmgWOGMjv2o52WGGaoVsLfJHPyrp7uLuYsq3VrLnnMRyaIrfSw/au2kiVX4HUhvBFOd5GHiRqXSfMiRqd4sj+DLSLlMMSw+LtyWWhlX1Sr4pcTFqa9EDrwdDuhpTWoagTVQP/4FTLl2pncd/zZso5MB+tjX72T/YjUnBuQyPqtjQPDiNMgm+M4lz6d3GZZvOHV05gWXr+aTgCAnTKPje8DBwNFLs5XgBIascUqRVz1k1v8n7B8lRxg1yOlqg==
```

or that for the case 2 :

```
e0Gm+MnmGvpFXhNDoj0Vsdl+1v+xxqW7uFFLBeGTjrcAr+ON7CadR0KFQ6lffEiZ17PAA584gDdLOtvpOH3q8V1UIqhbLQhJwEPstkBZRMNsplJse+eBsHNPnev2JYBDABbnAhE7I+xM9mI8iTCjW0DTcAecXahN+UctzBlKveZBMOcnJsRhgfYGZ7SKPySysIc6QoTkiNEJCgb68S8mfsiX9KSDgCwfc50Rql2nKEc15nO83OtkFvuLAjGxsQdSytzQ3hUuLXKqvEqeZsIgYYwQwbKWpLlJuFFQWL3VyjhupnBIO0tDRbZ/Lhqr62DhAoWkKjFtQiHdGdDv407xPQ==
```

I have correct privateKey.

Can you guys help me ? Thank you :)

Comment: Both variants allow the creation of a signature, but `openssl_sign` is more direct and therefore simpler, since only the data to be signed has to be passed. With `openssl_private_encrypt` the data to be signed must first be hashed manually (here with SHA256) and the ID belonging to SHA256 must be prefixed, [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#page-47). Neither of these is done, which is probably the reason for the different results. By the way, in `openssl_sign` _sha256WithRSAEncryption_ must be passed as a string.

Comment: Thank you,  now I encode first my data in sha256 for the second case. But what do you mean by "the ID belonging to SHA256 must be prefixed" ?

Comment: When signing with PKCS1-v1_5, the padding variant [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-8.2) described in RFC8017 is used. Its format is described in [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5, step 5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#page-46). The DER encoding `T` must be passed to `openssl_private_encrypt` as first parameter and equals the [hash ID](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#page-47) followed by the hash value of the data to be signed `$data`, e.g. for SHA256: `hex2bin("3031300d060960864801650304020105000420").hash("sha256",$data,true)`.

Comment: By the way JWT uses _base64url_ and not _base64_ as signature-encoding, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token#Structure). For PHP see also [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php#121767).

Comment: My project is progressing thanks to you, but I don't really understand the "DER encoding T part"